# error(ignoring discrete feature) in Orange tool hierarchical clustering

Tags: orange

I am new to orange tool. Using hierarchical clustering i load the data set as .csv format. When i open distances tool it shows error like ignoring discrete feature or continuous.

Please anyone help me to recover the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Please provide us your code, it will be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: I used tools for hierarchical clustering. It is already present in tutorial. No codes sir

Comment: Not being about programming, this question seems more appropriate for [DataScience StackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orange). [Orange agrees](http://orange.biolab.si/community/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing distances, Orange ignores discrete (categorical) features as the distance between two orthogonal values is dubious. If you want distances to take in account the discrete features, you have to pass your data through Continuize widget first.

Comment: Ya it's working. Thank you for your valuable information